# Getting IE Browser to open the File

Tags: c, winapi, com, ole

I embed the default Internet Explorer in my win32-C Application via COM/OLE. 
I display a web page having a link (anchor tag) to save/open a file. 
When i click on the link, It does some processing in the background but does not give me a dialog box asking to save or open the file. From Fiddler I come to know that it is writing to the cache but not able to access it or show any popup.

I expect to see the dialog box asking me to either save or open the file (default)

If i do this from the IE browser then everything works fine.

EDIT : I tried a [sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla) in which I do get to see the [Dialog Box](http://imageshack.us/f/204/stdapp.png) providing me with the option of saving, opening the file although tallied everything with [my code](http://imageshack.us/f/651/myappb.png) I still fail to see the box.

I was thinking of the Modeless Dialog Box issue but I can see a [Message Box](http://imageshack.us/f/21/modeless.png) in my code. So modeless dialog box is not disabled.

Not able to get how to get it to work.

(Note: Please see the attached images)

EDIT: I edited the The EmbedBrowser Function in my code, my browser was not given a pointer to my IOleClientSite object

New Code :- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1062010/

But problem persists!

Comment: "via C shell"? Can you elaborate, maybe showing us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.
The interface DWebBrowserEvents2's invoke method was implemented to not display the File download Box while downloading. 
Modified it to allow the same.